# Sending two serial signals down a single twisted pair?

Tags: serial, twisted-pair

Let's say I have two serial signals that need to be sent down a cable. This cable features a twisted pair along with a single common wire. If I were to place each serial signal onto one of the twisted pair conductors, how bad would this be?

I realize I wouldn't gain the benefit of common noise rejection had I used the twisted pair to send a differential signal, but would I ruin the quality of each signal by using a twisted pair?

Question: Would each signal in the twisted pair induce voltages into the opposite conductor thus reducing the signal quality? Or would I be better off to have these signals NOT be in a twisted pair? I'm essentially trying to determine whether or not I can be economical with my conductors, or if I should separate them.

Comment: It depends on the nature of the signals. Their frequency, amplitude and noise tolerance. There will be a crosstalk, but sometimes you can live with it.

Comment: Yeah that would make sense. I'm assuming it would be best to pair low frequency signals and high frequency signals as opposed to two high frequency signals? As example, I would be better off pairing a 5V DC signal with a 5V serial signal rather than pairing two 5V serial signals?

Comment: How long is the cable? I'm sure there are simple ways to multiplex the multiple serial signals and send them over the same twisted pair.

Comment: Van you pair 5V DC and the GND? It will solve your problem.

Comment: @pipe The cable at a maximum should only be 12". I suppose I could look into that, but I think that would just add more complexity.

Comment: There are encoding methods especially suited for this if you actually run into problems. Twisted pair or not depends on several HF factors. Ethernet CAT6 cable has a different amount of twist for different pairs to reduce crosstalk. Is this something you can exploit? See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/20023/why-does-usb-have-4-lines-instead-of-3

Comment: @pipe Simple? It will require some extras on the both ends anyway.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I could do that. However, I've got a few different signals like UART, SPI, I2C, 5V analog signal, 5V, 3.3V, GND. I'm trying to determine the best pairs.

Comment: Best pairs would be differential signals. Power pairs are naturally differential.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Absolutely extras. But I was under the assumption that the cable was at least 10 metres or something, meaning that it's cheaper to put two adapters on the ends than it is to replace the cable.

Comment: **1)** What are the frequencies and amplitudes (voltage and current) of the signals? **2)** How many twists per inch? **3)** What are the diameters of the conductors? **4)** What material is the insulation made from and what's its diameter? **5)** Is this commercial cable? If so, who's the manufacturer and what's the cable's part number? **6)** is the cable shielded?

Comment: @EMFields Hi EMFields, thanks for the response. I'm currently looking at transmitting SPI, I2C, UART, via a single HDMI cable. I realize there are concerns regarding this, however, the typical usage is just a direct plug in with HDMI receptacle and plug (i.e. no cable), I'm simply looking to see how feasible it would be to add a cable.

Comment: Is this question at all different to this one you raised a few days ago: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246161/what-are-the-effects-of-single-ended-signals-on-twisted-pair-conductors

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, that question was inspired by a completely separate application where I was implementing high speed serial. I was curious of the effects of a "hanging" or unused twisted pair conductor.

Comment: The inspiration may be different but the question remains largely the same.

Comment: Yteague, you wrote: "Hi EMFields, thanks for the response. I'm currently looking at transmitting SPI, I2C, UART, via a single HDMI cable." If you'd have stated that up front it would certainly have saved everyone a lot of time and, I suspect, aggravation. Go [**here**](https://www.google.com/search?q=hdmi+cable+construction&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizwaPmyYfOAhUozIMKHRMkCDYQ7AkIOQ&biw=1280&bih=937) for a clue.

Comment: @EMFields This question was posed more general such that future users could reference the question including those who aren't working with HDMI. I was attempting to get some general responses regarding past experiences on signal coupling in doing what I described.

Comment: If you'e working with HDMI, then your question should include that information in order that a proper solution be found for **YOU**  by eliminating the inevitable confusion caused by asking a generic  question with dubious relevance later.  Now, since you say you want to use an HDMI cable, can you edit your question with a schematic showing how you plan to do signal routing and timing diagrams showing signal edge rise and fall times, frequencies and amplitudes, please?

Answer (score 1):

First you say you have ONE twisted pair, and then you say "one of the twisted pairs".  We will assume that you really have only ONE pair and you meant to say "one of the wires of the twisted pair".

You are correct that unless you have rather low-frequency signals and a quite short (perhaps 1m) cable, you will likely experience bad to severe "crosstalk" between the two signals because they are so effectively capacitively coupled together by the twisted geometry.

There are ways of sending two different signals over a pair including time-domain and frequency-domain multiplexing. And using a [Phantom Circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_circuit).

Comment: I forgot the word 'conductor'. I added it.